# Unusual variable declaration in C++

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

```
// s isn't declared before
std::string(s);
s = "Hellow world";
```

It compiles and works as if s was declared as usual at least on msvc and gcc (C++14).

Why is it so? Did not find explanation in standard. Does it contradicts the standard?

Comment: `std::string(s);` is a valid declaration of `s`.

Comment: No, it doesn't contradict the standard. http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.meaning-6